# Combine JPA with HIbernate Search Lucene Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I can easily search my JPA entities with a fulltext query using Hibernate Search:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = 
        Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
        .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(MyBean.class).get();

org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
        .onFields("foo", "bar").matching("needle").createQuery();

javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager
        .createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, MyBean.class);

List<MyBean> fulltextResult = jpaQuery.getResultList();
```

And that's great. But, how can I combine the `luceneQuery` in an existing JPA Query? For example as a predicate to use in a `CriteriaBuilder.where()` expression. I think this could be possibile since Hibernate Search retrieves the entity identifiers from its indexes and finally use them in a JPA query to get the result, but I don't know if there is any method beside `getResultList()` to get the query in other intermediate types, such as a `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate`.

Comment: Interesting question. I didn't even know it was possible.

Comment: have you found your way ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [projections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=5.6#projections) to only retrieve the identifiers from lucene, and then use them to pass in to e.g. an `in` expression of your jpa query.